# Jenkins Configuration for Webpack

Tags: angular, jenkins, webpack

I'm trying to build my angular 2 code using webpack on Jenkins. Are there any configurations I need to change or implement in order to make the build successful?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is absolutely possible to implement what you have described. After all, Jenkins is essentially a button-based GUI which is really driven by the custom shell scripts behind it which we all have to write ourselves. In other words, any instance of Jenkins is only as powerful/capable as we make it.

Regarding the integration of AngularJS 2, webpack, and Jenkins specifically, I have found two links which may be helpful to you:

[Angular 2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/ZombieHippie/angular-2-webpack-starter)

[Continuous Integration for AngularJS Applications with Jenkins](https://www.cardinalsolutions.com/blog/2014/07/continuous_integrati)

Additionally, there are several plugins you may want to consider if you have not already. Regarding testing integration in Jenkins specifically for Angular, I would recommend Karma:

[Karma Jenkins Plugin](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/Jenkins-CI.html)